# How do i add a string to the List on the start of the List?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++)
{

    string startTag = FirstTags[i];
    string endTag = LastTags[i];
    startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag);
    while (startIndex > 0)
    {

        endIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        string t = Maps[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
        }

        position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
        startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag, position);

    }

    imagesSatelliteUrls = imagesSatelliteUrls.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

So the first itertion/loop i = 0
Then its getting into a while loop.
Then i did:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
}
```

So in the end imagesSatelliteUrls contain 9 files.
I want to add another index to the beginning of the imagesSatelliteUrls List.
A string so index 0 will be for example: "Group 1"
And then the rest 9 index will be the files.

But how do i add only once and to the beginning of the List the string: "Group 1" ?
So in the end the List should look like:

```
index[0] "Group 1"
index[1] file 1
index[2] file 2
.
.
.
.
index[9] file 9
```

So i know that "Group 1" is from 1 to 9.

Comment: Find whatever you need [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: Use insert method with 0 index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your loop ends then

write this code

```
imagesSatelliteUrls.Insert(0, "Group 1");
```

This will insert "Group 1" at the First location i.e index zero.